# Using two patterns in regex findall without creating tuples

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract data from 500+ files which look like that:

```
1.   Site Identification of the GNSS Monument

     Site Name                : Aeroport du Raizet -LES ABYMES - Météo France
     Four Character ID        : ABMF
     Monument Inscription     : NONE
     IERS DOMES Number        : 97103M001
     CDP Number               : NONE
     Monument Description     : INOX TRIANGULAR PLATE ON TOP OF METALLIC PILAR
       Height of the Monument : 2.0 m
       Monument Foundation    : ROOF
       Foundation Depth       : 4.0 m
     Marker Description       : TOP AND CENTRE OF THE TRIANGULAR PLATE
     Date Installed           : 2008-07-15T00:00Z
```

And I'm looking for `Date Installed` which comes in two different formats: `CCYY-MM-DDThh:mmZ` or `CCYY-MM-DD`. Right now I'm using pattern like this: `date_installed = re.findall("Date Installed\s*:\s*(.*?)T.*$", contents, re.MULTILINE)` but this only gets dates in `CCYY-MM-DDThh:mmZ`.

How can I modify my regex to extract both date formats without using `|` operator?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not using `|` operator ?

Comment: because then I'm getting lists of tuples insade a list and i dont know how to get rid of the tuples and have only parts that are not empty strings

Comment: Do you need the whole date row or just the date?

Comment: @Challe just the date

Comment: `"Date Installed\s*:\s*(.*?)(?:T.*)?$"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem by using `re.findall()` is that you need non-capturing groups for groups that should not be in the result. So the regex `/Date Installed\s*:\s*(.*?(?:T.*Z)?)$/` or `/Date Installed\s*:\s*(.*?)(?:T.*Z)?$/` should do the trick, see:

```py
re.findall("Date Installed\s*:\s*(.*?(?:T.*Z)?)$", contents, re.MULTILINE)
```

This would give you the whole date in form of `CCYY-MM-DDThh:mmZ` or `CCYY-MM-DD`.If you are interested only in the `CCYY-MM-DD` part, then simply move the non-capturing group out as shown in the second regex above:

```py
re.findall("Date Installed\s*:\s*(.*?)(?:T.*Z)?$", contents, re.MULTILINE)
```

See the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

> ```
> (?:...)
> ```
>
> A non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, but the substring matched by the group cannot be retrieved after performing a match or referenced later in the pattern.

Comment: it woud work but I want to cut the `Thh:mmZ` from the first format

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall("\d{4}\-[01]\d-[0-3]\dT[0-6]\d:\d{2}Z|\d{4}\-[01]\d-[0-3]\d", contents, re.MULTILINE)
```

This works and doesn't return a tuple in my testing.